# Is EBM music regularly played anywhere social in South East Asia?

Tags: culture, bangkok, cultural-awareness, music

[EBM music](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electronic_body_music) is an electronic "dark" and "underground" dance music with a few subtypes.

- Example: ["New School" subtype](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jPJV8_fUp64)
- Example: [Industrial subtype](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sfpjCKOjqEI&list=PLETr46v-Hknif7CVoS96dJShOPYobd0Cg)
- Example: [Anhalt subtype](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ynb986wl29M&list=PLETr46v-Hknif7CVoS96dJShOPYobd0Cg&index=2)

EBM music originated in Belgium and Germany and is played mostly throughout Europe; it has made its way into South American states (such as Colombia and Peru), USA and Israel as well (I don't know where else it is regularly played).

Is EBM music regularly played anywhere social in South East Asia (in go out places; dance bars, underground alternative parties, boat parties, street parties)?